# Linkage error while deploying Axis 1 on wildfly 10

Tags: java, wildfly, axis, wildfly-10

I am getting below exception while deploying Axis 1 on wildfly 10 and getting linkage error. :

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
>   method
>   "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class, org/apache/axis/utils/XMLUtils, and the class
>   loader (instance of ) for the method's defining class,
>   javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder, have different Class objects for
>   the type org/xml/sax/InputSource used in the signature

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005023: Exception handling request to /axis/servlet/AxisServlet: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/axis/utils/XMLUtils, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the method's defining class, javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder, have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/InputSource used in the signature
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:369)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:388)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
```

I have created below axis module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.axis">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="axis-1.4.jar" />
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <system export="true">
      <paths>
        <path name="org/xml/sax" />
        <path name="org/xml/sax/helpers" />
        <path name="javax/xml/parsers" />
        <path name="org/w3c/dom" />
      </paths>
    </system>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.discovery" />
    <module name="javax.mail.api" />
    <module name="javax.xml" />
  </dependencies>
</module>
```